# Very High Memory Usage in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, garbage-collection, rdlc

I have a C# Windows Service that I recently moved from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0. No other code changes were made.

When running on 3.5, memory utilzation for a given work load was roughly 1.5 GB of memory and throughput was 20 X per second. (The X doesn't matter in the context of this question.)

The exact same service running on 4.0 uses between 3GB and 5GB+ of memory, and gets less than 4 X per second. In fact, the service will typically end up stalling out as memory usage continue to climb until my system is siting at 99% utilization and page file swapping goes nuts.

I'm not sure if this has to do with garbage collection, or what, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. My window service uses the "Server" GC via the config file switch seen below:

```
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

Changing this option to false didn't seem to make a difference. Futhermore, from the reading I've done on the new GC in 4.0, the big changes only effect the workstation GC mode, not server GC mode. So perhaps GC has nothing to do with the issue.

Ideas?

Comment: Just double checking: _only_ the .NET framework changed. Or did you go from 32-bit machine to 64 bit? Did you go from DEP to no-DEP? Did you go from PAE to no-PAE? Did you go from ngen to JIT? Just hints to trigger more info

Comment: Not enough information here to even hazard a guess. Are you by chance using the `BlockingCollection` or `ConcurrentQueue` classes? `ConcurrentQueue` has a memory leak, which could be an issue.

Comment: ConcurrentQueue didn't exist in .NET 3.5, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: @phoog: Actually, `ConcurrentQueue` did exist in the Parallel Extensions to .NET. Converting from 3.5 to 4.0 could have involved replacing that with `System.Collections.Concurrent`. I know that I did when we converted to 4.0.

Comment: *Only* the framework change. Same machine. Same everything.

No .NET 4.0 specific APIs or libs are being used - so no TPL, no Concurrent anything.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Aha, thanks for setting me right. But wouldn't the OP have had to change references and/or namespace `using` statements if these classes were in use?

Comment: @phoog: Yes, references and usings would have to change. The OP said "no *other* code changes were made." He didn't indicate that NO code changes were made.

Comment: `I experienced the same problem in .NET 4.5 in ASP.NET based application with heavy use of dynamic types for serialization and deserialization.  So I could not use  <trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>, `

Adrian Nichols has a helper code in

***https://github.com/AdrianNichols/ssrs-non-native-functions/blob/17ee83c9988acc638eb11f961caf0b2a6b77b555/SSRS_Demo/Business/reportHelper.cs***

`Keys`: ***`RenderReportToMemoryAsPDFInAnotherAppDomain`*** Method and ***`ReportHelperInAppDomain`***  class

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Well this was an interesting one.

The root cause turns out to be a change in the behavior of SQL Server Reporting Services' LocalReport class (v2010) when running this on top of .NET 4.0.

Basically, Microsoft altered the behavior of RDLC processing so that each time a report was processed it was done so in a seperate application domain. This was actually done specifically to address a memory leak caused by the inability to unload assemblies from app domains. When the LocalReport class processed an RDLC file, it actually creates an assembly on the fly and loads it into the app domain.

In my case, due to the large volume of report I was processing, this was resulting in very large numbers of System.Runtime.Remoting.ServerIdentity objects being created. This was my tip off to the cause, as I was confused as to why processing an RLDC required remoting.

Of course, to call a method on a class in another app domain, remoting is exactly what you use. In .NET 3.5, this wasn't necessary as, by default, the RDLC-assembly was loaded into the same app domain. In .NET 4.0, however, a new app domain is created by default.

The fix was fairly easy. First I needed to go enable legacy security policy using the following config:

```
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

Next, I needed to force the RDLCs to be processed in the same app domain as my service by calling the following:

```
myLocalReport.ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
```

This resolved the issue.

Comment: Thx for reporting this. Shame we can't upvote the question more than once because this is a very very good find and deserves to be well-indexed on SO

Comment: I'm not sure how you tracked down this fix, but bravo!

Comment: ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain is deprecated according to the documentation.  And even with it, there's still a memory leak because every time a report runs, those calculation DLLs are re-created and then left unused but not unloaded.  The only way we found to get around this was to spawn a new process each time we wanted to run a report.  When the process dies, EVERYTHING is automatically released, including the no-longer-needed DLLs.  Just a thought to consider when you work with MS reporting.

Comment: Cheers for sharing this. I also ran into the memory leaks, even in vs2010 sp1, and solved it by running the localreport.render() stuff in a separate appdomain, which I unloaded when done. Seems to work well for me.

Comment: This was an issue that had been plaguing us for a long time. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: If the RDLC processing was moved to a different app domain to stop memory leaks, why would you want to move that to the current app domain? Seems like a trade off of one memory leak for another.

Comment: @Robert - what I'm finding is that using the new `AppDomain` stuff all memory is *eventually* released but it hangs around a *long time* (like 10 or 15 minutes).  The Sandbox `AppDomain` does get released quickly, but what @RMD is talking about are the remoting objects in your main `AppDomain`.  These stick around for a long time *and* they keep a reference to the `LocalReport` object.  That means lots of memory is still held onto until the remoting objects decide to die off.  That takes a while.  If you're processing a lot of reports fast, this adds up.

Comment: This is crazy, how are people not screaming about this issue?  It still exists in .NET 4.5.

Comment: RMD's solution does work, but if you make any reference to 'dynamic' in your application it will fail miserably.

Comment: @JohanDanforth Could you perhaps give an example of doing the render in a seperate appdomain?

Comment: @RolandDeschain I'll have to see if I can get hold of the source again as I don't have access to it on my computer anymore...

Comment: Champion! Thanks for fix. Ants profiler showed it was reporting services but I wasnt able to narrow it down to the root cause.

Comment: @RMD My report every time you start devouring + 2MB memory, I beg you, please help me, here's a link http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582609/Отследить-потерю-памяти-winforms/582636?noredirect=1#comment776018_582636 to my problem.

Comment: @Winteriscoming See my answer at the bottom. Should help!

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this exact issue. And it is true that app domains are created and not cleaned up. However I wouldn't recommend reverting to legacy. They can be cleaned up by ReleaseSandboxAppDomain().

```
LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
...
report.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
```

Some other things I also do to clean up:

Unsubscribe to any SubreportProcessing events,
Clear Data Sources,
Dispose the report.

Our windows service processes several reports a second and there are no leaks.

Comment: Thanks, I see after testing what you said above is working and I see the report not leaking anymore. :)
This is specifically what I did.  I hope it helps someone else:
localReport.SubreportProcessing -= reportDataProcessor.SubreportProcessingHandler;
localReport.DataSources.Clear();
localReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
localReport.Dispose();

Comment: This didn't seem to change anything for me.  Still had a nasty memory leak, even with all of the suggested clean-up.

Comment: So, this works for me but only if I enable CAS via the app.config.  sues999, I am thinking you have this flag turned on or are running .NET 3.5 or earlier.  ReleaseSandboxAppDomain() doesn't do anything unless a sandbox app domain is created, which requires CAS.  By default, with CAS enabled, LocalReport will use a sandbox AppDomain, so it kind of seems like the selected answer poster has it backwards.  I expect in .NET 4.0 the report runs in the current app domain by default, which is why it leaks.  Only an AppDomain teardown seems to free up what the report generation leaves behind.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty late to this, but I have a real solution and can explain why!

It turns out that LocalReport here is using .NET Remoting to dynamically create a sub appdomain and run the report in order to avoid a leak internally somewhere.  We then notice that, eventually, the report will release all the memory after 10 to 20 minutes.  For people with a lot of PDFs being generated, this isn't going to work.  However, the key here is that they are using .NET Remoting.  One of the key parts to Remoting is something called "Leasing".  Leasing means that it will keep that Marshal Object around for a while since Remoting is usually expensive to setup and its probably going to be used more than once.  LocalReport RDLC is abusing this.

By default, the leasing time is... 10 minutes!  Also, if something makes various calls into it, it adds another 2 minutes to the wait time! Thus, it can randomly be between 10 and 20 minutes depending how the calls line up.  Luckily, you can change how long this timeout happens.  Unluckily, you can only set this once per app domain... Thus, if you need remoting other than PDF generation, you will probably need to make another service running it so you can change the defaults.  To do this, all you need to do is run these 4 lines of code at startup:

```
    LifetimeServices.LeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    LifetimeServices.LeaseManagerPollTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    LifetimeServices.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    LifetimeServices.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

You'll see the memory use start to rise and then within a few seconds you should see the memory start coming back down.  Took me days with a memory profiler to really track this down and realize what was happening.

You can't wrap ReportViewer in a using statement (Dispose crashes), but you should be able to if you use LocalReport directly.  After that disposes, you can call GC.Collect() if you want to be doubly sure you are doing everything you can to free up that memory.

Hope this helps!

*Edit*

Apparently, you should call GC.Collect(0) after generating a PDF report or else it appears the memory use could still get high for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to

- [profile the heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309515.aspx)
- use [WinDbg + SOS.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) to establish what resource is being leaked and from where the reference is held

Perhaps some API has changed semantics or there might even be a bug in the 4.0 version of the framework

Comment: Interestingly, I did run CLR Profiler. When Task Manager showed a 1.5 GB of memory usage, the "root" heap showed less than 400MB of usage.

In other words, unless I'm understanding this wrong, there was 1.1 GB of uncollected garbage.

Similarly, when the service was using 2.4 GB according to Task Manager, CLR Profiler showed the root to be 1.1 GB.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, as it was a good suggestion, just not the complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, if anyone is looking for the equivalent `ASP.Net web.config` setting, it is:

```
  <system.web>
    <trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>
  </system.web>
```

`ExecuteReportInCurrentAppDomain` works the same.

Thanks to this [Social MSDN reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you cannot use dynamic types with legacy cas model - usage of ViewBag will result in exception.

Comment: Yes we're looking into this and get this exception when running it on the web version: Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Comment: `I experienced the same problem in .NET 4.5 in ASP.NET based application with heavy use of dynamic types for serialization and deserialization.  So I could not use  <trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>, `

Adrian Nichols has a helper code in

***https://github.com/AdrianNichols/ssrs-non-native-functions/blob/17ee83c9988acc638eb11f961caf0b2a6b77b555/SSRS_Demo/Business/reportHelper.cs***

`Keys`: ***`RenderReportToMemoryAsPDFInAnotherAppDomain`*** Method and ***`ReportHelperInAppDomain`***  class

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though Microsoft tried putting the report into its own separate memory space to work around all of the memory leaks rather than fix them. In doing so, they introduced some hard crashes, and ended up having more memory leaks *anyway*. They seem to cache the report definition, but never use it and never clean it up, and every new report creates a new report definition, taking up more and more memory.

I played around with doing the same thing: use a separate app domain and marshal the report over to it. I think that is a terrible solution and makes a mess very quickly.

What I did instead is similar: split the reporting part of your program out into its own separate reports program. This turns out to be a good way to organize your code anyway.

The tricky part is passing information to the separate program. Use the `Process` class to start a new instance of the reports program and pass any parameters it needs on the command line. The first parameter should be an enum or similar value indicating the report that should be printed. My code for this  in the main program looks something like:

```
const string sReportsProgram = "SomethingReports.exe";

public static void RunReport1(DateTime pDate, int pSomeID, int pSomeOtherID) {
   RunWithArgs(ReportType.Report1, pDate, pSomeID, pSomeOtherID);
}

public static void RunReport2(int pSomeID) {
   RunWithArgs(ReportType.Report2, pSomeID);
}

// TODO: currently no support for quoted args
static void RunWithArgs(params object[] pArgs) {
   // .Join here is my own extension method which calls string.Join
   RunWithArgs(pArgs.Select(arg => arg.ToString()).Join(" "));
}

static void RunWithArgs(string pArgs) {
   Console.WriteLine("Running Report Program: {0} {1}", sReportsProgram, pArgs);
   var process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo.FileName = sReportsProgram;
   process.StartInfo.Arguments = pArgs;
   process.Start();
}
```

And the reports program looks something like:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] pArgs) {
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

   var reportType = (ReportType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReportType), pArgs[0]);
   using (var reportForm = GetReportForm(reportType, pArgs))
      Application.Run(reportForm);
}

static Form GetReportForm(ReportType pReportType, string[] pArgs) {
   switch (pReportType) {
      case ReportType.Report1: return GetReport1Form(pArgs);
      case ReportType.Report2: return GetReport2Form(pArgs);
      default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pReportType", pReportType, null);
   }
}
```

Your `GetReportForm` methods should pull the report definition, make use of relevant arguments to obtain the dataset, pass the data and any other arguments to the report, and then place the report in a report viewer on a form and return a reference to the form. Note that it is possible to extract much of this process so that you can basically say 'give me a form for this report from this assembly using this data and these arguments'.

Also note that both programs must be able to see your data types that are relevant to this project, so hopefully you have extracted your data classes into their own library, which both of these programs can share a reference to. It would not work to have all of the data classes in the main program, because you would have a circular dependency between the main program and the report program.

Don't over do it with the arguments, either. Do any database querying you need in the reports program; don't pass a huge list of objects (which probably wouldn't work anyway). You should just be passing simple things like database ID fields, date ranges, etc. If you have particularly complex parameters, you might need to push that part of the UI to the reports program too and not pass them as arguments on the command line.

You can also put a reference to the reports program in your main program, and the resulting .exe and any related .dlls will be copied to the same output folder. You can then run it without specifying a path and just use the executable filename by itself (ie: "SomethingReports.exe"). You can also remove the reporting dlls from the main program.

One issue with this is that you will get a manifest error if you've never actually published the reports program. Just dummy publish it once, to generate a manifest and then it will work.

Once you have this working, it's very nice to see your regular program's memory stay constant when printing a report. The reports program appears, taking up more memory than your main program, and then disappears, cleaning it up completely with your main program taking up no more memory than it already had.

Another issue might be that each report instance will now take up more memory than before, since they are now entire separate programs. If the user prints a lot of reports and never closes them, it will use up a lot of memory very fast. But I think this is still much better since that memory can easily be reclaimed simply by closing the reports.

This also makes your reports independent of your main program. They can stay open even after closing the main program, and you can generate them from the command line manually, or from other sources as well.