# System.TypeAccessException when running unit test

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, xunit.net

I'm using xunit to write some unit tests that will be testing a subclass of `HttpClient` that I've written that also uses a `DelegateHandler`. I'm trying to use a `HttpMessageHandler` to mock the responses that I'd be getting from calling the Get/Post calls on the `HttpClient`. I'm passing the message handler to my delete handler's constructor through a `HttpClientHandler.CreatePipeline()` call. However, when I run the unit test, I get this exception:

```
System.TypeAccessException : Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler>)' to access security critical type 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler' failed.
   Stack Trace:
        at System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, IEnumerable`1 handlers)
```

My constructor looks like this:

```
    public MyHttpClient(HttpMessageHandler handler) :
        base(HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
            new HttpClientHandler(),
            new[]
            {
                new MyDelegateHandler(handler)
            }))
    { }
```

Constructor for my delegate handler:

```
    public MyDelegateHandler(HttpMessageHandler messageHandler) : 
        base(messageHandler)
    { }
```

And some code from my unit test:

```
        var handler = new MyMessageHandler("response content");
        MyHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(handler);
        var task = client.GetAsync("https://example.com");
```

(note that the exception occurs before I get to call `GetAsync()`)

I've tried adding security attributes to all my calls, including the method that runs the unit test (from this question: [Attempt by security transparent method X to access security critical method Y failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885764/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-x-to-access-security-critical-method-y-fa))

I've also tested by removing the delegate handler completely and passing the message handler directly into the `MyHttpClient` constructor and that works fine.

I've also tried adding any number/combination of the following attributes to the `AssemblyInfo.cs` files:

```
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
[assembly: SecurityTransparent()]
```

Is there anything else I can do to get around the access exception? I'd like to be able to test the delegate handler.

UPDATE: It appears I am getting this exception whether I am passing in a message handler or not. Simply calling the `CreatePipeline()` method throws this exception.

Comment: Any possible solutions / own ansewrs?

Comment: @F.I.V No solution as far as I know, since I had time constraints, I just wrote my unit tests without using delegate handlers