# Memory leaks in the LocalReport object of .Net

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, reporting, localreport

Some one know if the LocalReport object of Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms has some memory leak issue. I'm having some memory leak problems and my main suspect is the LocalReport object.

Answer (score 1):

According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6221590/3343137 it here are issues with how rdlc are loaded into new app domains each time they are accessed.