# Asp.Net RDLC ReportViewer Memory Issue

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, reportviewer

I am using the RDLC report with reportviewer to generate the byte array and it's being rendered as PDF in a web page. 
 After a while when more users are accessing the page to download the PDF array, my server memory is spiking up.

I emptied the with the below code

```
 bytearray={0}
```

and I tried to dispose the reportviewer also with the below code.

```
 reportviewer.Dispose().
```

But this also didn't help me. What are the other possibilities to could go wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem with ReportViewer in a WinForms application and I solve using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6221590/2400834
I don't know if it also works with asp.net.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and but unfortunately it's not reducing memory consumption.